# Compass/sass alternatives for Java

Tags: java, css, maven, compass-sass

We are using Compass/SASS for our CSS with maven plugin which does this with JRuby and it is EXTREMELY slow. It takes over 4 minutes to compile our CSS on the latest i7 with 16Gb of memory available to Java.
Our maven plugin looks like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>de.saumya.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>gem-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.29.4</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compassProcessSource</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <execArgs>${project.build.directory}/rubygems/bin/compass  compile -c ./compass/config.rb --time  --sass-dir=${basedir}/src/main/java/com/company/ --css-dir=${project.build.directory}/classes/com/company/ --output-style=${pom.compass.compression.style}</execArgs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Are there any alternative to compass which are more performant?
Or is there a way to run it faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend trying out Wellington, http://getwt.io. I'm the author of Wellington an Open Source spriting tool that supports Sass syntax. It is an order of magnitude faster than Compass.

Answer (score 0):

there should be some java implementations. for example tapestry plans to use (or is using already) one. but think if that's what you really want to do? those are front-end tools. they came from ruby/nodejs world. why do you have to port them to java? just install nodejs and ruby on your dev machine and your CI and you will get the speed of native/default implementation

Comment: My goal is to make compilation work faster. Did I get you right that just migrating from JRuby to regular ruby will speed it up?

Comment: i said it could. don't limit yourself to java only because your backend is in java. furthermore, we use the native tools support (ruby + nodejs) and we don't have to compile it to run locally. we only need to compile before the deployment - that's a huge speed up of everyday development

Comment: Can you please rephrase your answer to advice to use native pre-installed tools so I can accept it as an answer?